# Character or Tag that Uses No Space

Tags: html, tags, special-characters

I've been searching for a character code or HTML tag to use in a div that takes up no space.

I don't have the option of hiding the div or masking the content, so I'm looking for any particular character or tag that would place content in the div, but show nothing and take up no space. (i.e. `&nbsp;` wouldn't be an option since it actually renders a character)

This div cannot be empty, thus nothing isn't a viable option.

Comment: Why not just actually use nothing?

Comment: The div cannot be empty.

Comment: If you can tell us why it can't be empty, we can give a better answer.

Comment: My character amount has to be exactly a certain number, and thus, I can't add a character (but must fill this div).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space is one idea. `&#8203;` in HTML. Not sure about cross-browser support though.

Comment: Can anyone comment on browser support outside of IE6 and below (as the article states)?

Comment: IE 6 shows the character as a small rectangle, because it cannot find a glyph for it and does not know that it need not.

Answer (score 0):

To create zero space, I use:

```
<img src="clearspace.gif" style="height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;">
```

One Example:  Used when I want to  have  display as shown here, without causing browser to show it as a link.  Written as below, all browsers show it as `" <link> "` without recognizing it as such.

```
<img src="clearspace.gif" style="height:0px; width:0px; border:0px; "link>
```

This requires that you have an actual gif (clearspace.gif or whatever you name it) uploaded to your site, otherwise there is a browser indication (small square) showing where the gif should be.  And since it is rendered dimensionless by you, the actual gif can be anything.